# What does the index of a normal subgroup tell us about the order of the larger group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $N\vartriangleleft G$ and $(G:N)=n<\infty$ does that tell us anything about the order of $G$?

I know that it means that there are $n$ cosets of $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have $|G| = (G:N)|N|$.  This is known as Lagrange's Theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory).

Comment: This makes sense. What about a case where $G$ and $N$ are not finite? Can we have a case where $|G|$, $|N|$, and $(G:N)$ are all infinite?

Comment: Sure, that's not a problem.  The equation $|G| = (G:N)|N|$ still holds when interpreted as infinite cardinals using cardinal arithmetic.